# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias mykey already exists

Tags: certificate, java-11, keytool

I am trying to install a client certificate in my JVM to call a https soap service, but when running the 
keytool -import command I get the below error:

** 
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias  already exists
**

Here is the command I am using, please note I am using Java11

**
C:\Softwares\java-11-openjdk-11.0.7.10-1.windows.redhat.x86_64\lib\security>keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file "C:\Softwares\client.certificate.pfx"
**

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Every entry in the java keystore is identified by a key called `alias`. It has to be unique for a given keystore. If you don't provide one, the default value the `keytool` uses is `mykey`. Looks like there is an entry with mykey already in your keystore. All you have to do is give a name yourself. You can do this using the `alias` attribute, like this:

> keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file "C:\Softwares\client.certificate.pfx" **-alias third_party_ca**

You can use any name as long as it is unique.